# форма в ajax и html

Tags: html, ajax, form

почему когда отправляешь форму через обычный html запрос страница меняется на адрес url, а когда делаешь тоже самое через ajax остаешься на той же странице

```
<form id="search">
<input type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Search"> <button type="submit">Search</button>
```

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/search',
        type: 'GET',
        data: data,
        contentType: 'application/json'
```

после нажатия кнопки submit адрес вот такой
http://localhost:8080/?text=

а когда отправляю через форму

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
<input type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Search"> <button type="submit">Search</button>
```

тогда адрес http://localhost:8080/search?text=

Comment: В первых двух строчках вопроса заключен ответ. Только уберите слово "почему".

Comment: можно ли сделать чтобы и ajax перекидывал на новый url http://localhost:8080/search?text=

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, что в случае с `ajax` Вам вообще не надо никуда никого "перекидывать". А просто надо отключить стандартный механизм отправки формы по нажатию кнопки:

```
<form id="search">
  <input type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Search"> 
  <button type="button">Search</button> <!-- !!! вместо "submit" -->
```

или

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/search',
    type: 'GET',
    data: data,
    contentType: 'application/json'
    ...
});
return false; // !!!
```